# jQuery serialize using rails doesn't work for custom ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, serialization, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm pretty sure this is some sort of Javascript error and not a Rails error after doing numerous puts() trials on my id's...

What I'm trying to do is serialize a bunch of li's using jQuery's serialize function. I want to do it based on a custom set of id's... In my case, podli-1, podli-2, podli-3, etc. I try to do this by using the option of serialize "expression".

What I get back from this when I try to debug it with alerts (as you can see below) is this: id=undefined&id=undefined&id=undefined&id=undefined&id=undefined&id=undefined&id=undefined

-- which is actually the right number of li's but for some reason all the id's are undefined. As I've said, it's all working within Rails, but there's some JS error.

Here's the Rails code.

```
<% @pods.each do |podli| %>
<% @podli = podli %>
<% @iden = 'podli-' << @podli.id.to_s %>
<li id="<%= @iden %>" class="ui-state-default">
   ....
</li>
<% end %>
```

And here's the javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
transitions();
//$( "#sortable" ).sortable({containment: 'parent'});
$(  "#sortable"  ).sortable({ items: '.ui-state-default', containment: 'parent'})//for moving the pods about
$( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
//$("#newspod" ).val("Enable Sort").closest("#newspod").removeClass("sortable")
$('#sortable').live('sortstop', function(event) {
    var u = $(this).sortable('serialize', { key: 'id', expression: /podli-\d/ })//  + '&index=' + jQuery(this).attr("id").substring(19);
    alert(u);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST', 
      data: { display_order: u },//$('#receiving-list').sortable('serialize')  + '&index=' + jQuery(this).attr("id").substring(19), 
      url: "<%= sort_dashboards_path %>"
    })

});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the "serialize" method (via the "sortable" plugin), your "expression" regex has to include a capturing group around whatever the value should be:

```
 var u = $(this).sortable('serialize', { key: 'id', expression: /podli-(\d+)/ });
```

By wrapping the "\d" (note that I couldn't help myself and I added "+" to that, in case you ever have more than 10) in parentheses, the plugin will get what it expects from your regex.

The jQuery UI documentation for that method is awful.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm going to mark this as solved but can you explain what a capturing group is and why I need it? (I realize it has something to do with what differentiates the li's -- their id numbers)